# How to block all but a specific list of IP addresses on a given port using IPSEC on Windows?

Tags: windows, blocking, ipsec

I have a list of IP addresses.

L={x.x.x.x,y.y.y.y,...etc}

I want to block all IP addresses except for the ones in the above list.

How to do using IPSEC commands in windows machine?

I tried to figure out from the following [Microsoft link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725926(v=ws.10).aspx). But no luck :-(

@Ramhound

My Goal: Block all ips on 198.18.84.161:80 except for the IP 198.18.84.162

I tried the following.

### 1)   To block all ips on port 80.

Steps:

netsh ipsec static add filterlist name=filterlist_198.18.84.161

netsh ipsec static add filter filterlist=filterlist_198.18.84.161 srcaddr=any dstaddr=Me
  protocol=tcp srcport=0 dstport=80

netsh ipsec static add filteraction name=action_198.18.84.161 action=block

netsh ipsec static add policy name=policy_198.18.84.161 assign=yes

netsh ipsec static add rule name=rule_198.18.84.161 policy=policy_198.18.84.161 
filterlist=filterlist_198.18.84.161 filteraction=action_198.18.84.161

Result: It blocked all ips on port 80

### 2)  To Allow IP 198.18.84.162 on port 80 of the machine 198.18.84.161

Steps:

netsh ipsec static add filterlist name=filterlist_198.18.84.162

netsh ipsec static add filter filterlist=filterlist_198.18.84.162 srcaddr=198.18.84.162 dstaddr=Me 
 protocol=tcp srcport=0 dstport=80

netsh ipsec static add filteraction name=action_198.18.84.162 action=permit

netsh ipsec static add policy name=policy_198.18.84.162 assign=yes

netsh ipsec static add rule name=rule_198.18.84.162 policy=policy_198.18.84.162 filterlist=filterlist_198.18.84.162 filteraction=action_198.18.84.162

Result: This unblocked all IPs on port 80 instead of only unblocking 198.18.84.162

Comment: Rahmund, Please see my updated description of the problem above.

Comment: Please don't write the answer in the question, please post the answer as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi All,
I found the answer my self.**

Below are the steps:

1.Block all Ips on Port 80

netsh ipsec static add filterlist name=filterlist_198.18.84.161

netsh ipsec static add filter filterlist=filterlist_198.18.84.161 **srcaddr=any** dstaddr=Me  protocol=tcp srcport=0 dstport=80

netsh ipsec static add filteraction name=action_198.18.84.161 **action=block**

netsh ipsec static add policy name=policy_198.18.84.161 assign=yes

netsh ipsec static add rule name=rule_198.18.84.161 **policy=policy_198.18.84.161** filterlist=filterlist_198.18.84.161 filteraction=action_198.18.84.161

2. Allow specfic Ip on port 80.

netsh ipsec static add filterlist name=filterlist_198.18.84.162

netsh ipsec static add filter filterlist=filterlist_198.18.84.162 **srcaddr=198.18.84.162** dstaddr=Me  protocol=tcp srcport=0 dstport=80

netsh ipsec static add filteraction name=action_198.18.84.162 **action=permit**

netsh ipsec static add rule name=rule_198.18.84.162 **policy=policy_198.18.84.161** filterlist=filterlist_198.18.84.162 filteraction=action_198.18.84.162

**The trick was use same policy for both the rules above.**